# How to change a custom customer attribute in code?

Tags: magento2.3

I have a customer attribute `account_manager_email` that I need to change for several customers. How do I go about changing that in PHP code?

Comment: do you want to update value for `account_manager_email` attribute for some customer ?

Comment: @Pawan Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.